# Can I log in to EWS with Conference room account credentials?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have been trying to do some operations via EWS API (for Java) by using credentials of the account marked as a conference room, with no success so far. Each call ends with `The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it`. I have been searching through EWS API reference but found no entry that Conference Room account or Resource account cannot be used to check its own calendar, schedule a meetings etc.

When I use my own credentials (personal, not conference room) same code works fine.

**The question**

Is it possible to read appointments using EWS using only Conference Room credentials?

Comment: The accounts associated with Room and Resource Mailboxes are disabled by default, have you enabled the account in AD ? Best practice would be to use a service account for you application and delegate that access to the Mailbox.

Comment: @Glen Scales: I thought so. Usage of additional service accounts was my first idea. Unfortunately I am not the administrator of the Exchange and the administrator forbids to add any additional accounts or change current accounts' settings. Does it mean that my goal is impossible to achieve using current settings?

Comment: The administrator is really taking the wrong approach using a service account will mean he as an administrator will have the ability to audit what your application is doing and also make sure the correct password policy is applied etc and disable it necessary if something goes wrong. If you enable the room account it should work okay but not a great idea